# Minumum velocity for Newton's approximation for penetration depth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Suppose a rod-like object of *length L* collides with high velocity into some target.

**Newton's approximation for the penetration depth** is

```
  penetration depth = L*density(object)/density(target)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth

**This is supposedly valid for *"high velocities"*** that are less than the speed of sound in the object and less than the speed of sound in the target. But no criterion for high velocities. What I would like to know is **what is the approximate minimum velocity** when Newton's approximation is usable?

For example, is that approximation about right if a metallic object collides another metallic object with 300 m/s velocity?

Answer (score 0):

300m/s is slow compared to the sound velocity in iron which is about 5000m/s, so  probably 300m/s will not make much of a dent.
But all these results are just very much approximations and one has just to do experiments, to decide.

Comment: Ok... yet if the velocity were the same or more than the velocity of sound in iron, the colliding object would not penetrate like a pencil into a birthday cake, but it would make a crater, and Newton's approximation would not be valid. For Newton's approximation, the velocity should be *less* than the speed of sound in the target.

Regrettably I don't have a possibility to test this with an experiment. 300 m/s metal bar colliding some other metal...